How can I use vba to send an email with an attachment from using the default email client?
I would like to be able to send an email with an attachment from Excel using vba and the default email client. So far I have this code that prints an Excel sheet and uses its data to create the filename and save it as PDF:
Sub ToPDFandSend()

    Dim filesave As FileDialog
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim PDFfileName As String
    Dim formatIndex As Long, i As Long
    
    'Variables to send email
    Dim thund As String
    Dim email As String
    Dim cc As String
    Dim bcc As String
    Dim subj As String
    Dim body As String
    
    Set filesave = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
    
    Select Case Sheets("Factura").Range("M1").Value
    Case 1: t = 1: f = 1 'page 1
    Case Else: f = 1: t = 2 'pages 1-2
End Select
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Factura")
        Set rng = .Range("A1:J97")
        Data = Format(Range("A13"), "YYYYMMDD")
        PDFfileName = .Range("H1").Value & " " & Range("A17").Value & " " & Data
    End With
    
    With filesave
        .Title = "Save as PDF"
        .InitialFileName = PDFfileName
        formatIndex = 0
        For i = 1 To .Filters.Count
            If InStr(1, .Filters(i).Extensions, "pdf", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then formatIndex = i
        Next
        If formatIndex > 0 Then .FilterIndex = formatIndex
        If .Show Then
            rng.ExportAsFixedFormat _
                Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                Filename:=.SelectedItems(1), _
                OpenAfterPublish:=False, _
                IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                IgnorePrintAreas:=True, _
                from:=f, _
                to:=t, _
                Quality:=xlQualityStandard
        End If
    
    End With
    email = "email@test.com"
    cc = "cc@test.com"
    bcc = "bcc@test.com"
    subj = "Subject"
    body = "body text"

    thund = "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird.exe" & _
            " -compose " & """" & _
            "to='" & email & "'," & _
            "cc='" & cc & "'," & _
            "bcc='" & bcc & "'," & _
            "subject='" & subj & "'," & _
            "body='" & body & "'" & """"

    Call Shell(thund, vbNormalFocus)
    
End Sub


I would like to attach this file to an email (using Thunderbird) with a given text for the subject and the body. Can anyone help?
-----EDITED QUESTION-----
I've progressed a little bit with the code above. Now I am able to open the client but I have no clue on how to add the attachment. Any help?
Thanks!

Apparently mailto opens directly the e-mail client (I have not tested it though) https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/a-macro-capable-of-creating-an-email-in-the-default-email-client.1189497/

Hi! I need to open the mail and attach a file. I'll keep looking. Thanks!

I'll check it. Thanks!
